# mysql data type for storing text(code) containing escape sequences

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on a project in which user will be able to store his code in database-server.

- The code can be from any language like c, c++, java, python. The code
  will contain escape sequences ('\n','\t') and significant
  spaces(specially for python).
- I want a data type which will store all this code as it is
  maintaining all spaces and escape sequences in code (without any
  formatting or anything).

I'm not sure about 'TEXT' MySQL data type, so what will be the best way to store this code as (raw data) in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

From the Manual.

> A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data. The four BLOB types are TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and LONGBLOB.

> BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.